# Help please with this SMD identification - SOT23-6 top marking F1TL

Tags: identification, surface-mount

[image][image: Photo of unknown device on PCB]

I need some help identifying this SMD part. It has F1TL marking and is on a 3-axis gimbal daughter board. There’s 3 on the board and 2 are burnt. Thanks in advance. [6-pin SMD, 3x2mm in size approx.]
2 more image’s, hope they help.I believe the gimbal ended up in the sea, the battery pack suffered, (replaced), I need to replace these so as to aid further testing. Strip down of the unit could be destructive.
[image]
Thank you for the help, I’ll do some more testing and see if the units repairable or scrap. Thanks again.

Comment: What does it connect to? Voltages?

Comment: Paul Rimmer - Hi, That looks like a SOT23-6 package so I added that & the main part of the top marking into the title, to help future searches. Can you also add a photo showing more of the PCB, to give some more context? Also, have you tried doing any reverse-engineering of the schematic, to help show how the unknown components are part of the overall design? If so ,please [edit] the question & add that image. The [current photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XXUr.jpg) shows the unknown device close to a connector. Are all 3 devices close to connectors? Do you know what event damaged the devices?

Comment: Paul Rimmer - Thanks for the update. (a) The photos show all 3 devices are near the same connector, so if the accident led to excessive / wrong polarity voltage on that connector, this could explain why 2 of the 3 devices were clearly damaged (and the 3rd one might be damaged internally too). (b) Now seeing the full PCB, it's not possible to reverse-engineer the relevant parts remotely using just the photos. However where we can see the PCB tracks going to those devices, we see that the tracks to pins 1 & 3 are thinner than others. That fits with the identification in [the answer](/a/609156).

Answer (score 9):

Most likely it is a AO6601 MOSFET, a complementary n and p channel pair in a single package.
[Here](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/marking/AO6601.pdf) is a package marking description.
And [here](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AO6601.pdf) is a datasheet.

Comment: Nice and welcome.